# Replacing Shimano RS21 rims

Tags: wheels, rims

I have damaged the rim of my rear Shimano RS21 wheel (unexpectedly hit a sharp kerb) which affects braking quite severely so I was wondering if it is possible to replace just the rim and not the whole wheel (the rest is in perfect condition). I've searched a number of online shops and none seem to offer Shimano rims, do Shimano not sell them separately?

Comment: It's almost impossible to source replacement rims/hubs for entry-level/factory-built Shimano wheels, unfortunately – I speak from experience.  (Although you can get replacement hub parts if you hunt around.)

Comment: Likely it will be just as economical to buy a new wheel.

Comment: Since Shimano sell entry level wheels in pairs (at least in my country) it would be a good idea to buy a pair and gain a spare front wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to replace it with the exact same rim. Your wheel doesn't appear to be anything exotic, so anything with the same diameter (700/622 bsd) and the same number of spokes (20?) should be compatible. You'll also probably want to look for something that is about the same width, although you can make small changes to this depending on your needs and availability.

Comment: Bear in mind that if the replacement rim has a different ERD (effective rim diameter) then you'll probably need new spokes as well, since the spoke length has to match the rim and hub dimensions.